# so far...as that

Tags: expressions

Charles Dickens wrote in his preface to *A Tale of Two Cities* the following sentence:

> I have **so far** verified what is done and suffered in these pages, **as** that I have certainly done and suffered it all myself.

I am wondering why "as" is used at all. Why not simply drop it?

Isn't the sentence of the type "so adj / adv...that..."?

Comment: It was written over 150 years ago. We wouldn't include ***as*** in such constructions today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm thinking that *as that* here is a synonym for *because* or *for*.

Comment: @tchrist: That would certainly sound more "acceptable" to our modern ear, but I'm not sure it doesn't slightly shift the nuance. I don't know too much about how ***certainly*** and ***so far*** could have been used then, but how about *...so **painstakingly** verified ... as **to have effectively** done and suffered it all myself*. Or (maybe a ***to*** too far :) how about *...as **to all intents and purposes** to have done it* ?

Comment: This is all the more puzzling because he also wrote, "in short, the period was so far like the present period, that some of its noisiest authorities insisted on its being received, for good or for evil, in the superlative degree of comparison only." (without as)

Answer (score -1):

We still use **so far as ...** today. Dickens' word order is poetic here, as well as a bit mawkish. Rearrange it slightly while substituting words one would be more likely to use today for those authors used back then, and everything is suddenly as clear as the April sky over Arizona:

> **So far as** my personal experience goes, everything described in these
>   pages is perfectly true, yo.

I hope this helps.